# VBA macro using Bloomberg terminal

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

I would like to create a VBA macro using Bloomberg.
The thing is that I have some ISIN number (=securities id), and I would like to ask VBA to search on bloomberg the price on that securities on a certain date (every information are on an Excel spreadsheet)
Does anybody has an idea of how I should proceed, the function I have to use etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will find the required add-ins and their documentation [here](http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/downloads/#office).

Answer (score 1):

There are examples (V3 Sample Documentation) available on Bloomberg at {https://blinks.bloomberg.com/screens/docs%202055451}.